# How to schedule a facebook page post?

Tags: java, facebook

I need to shedule a facebook post using an image. It should appear in the planner tool of the Meta Business Suite.

I found this example, but I can't figure out how to use an image and set a publication date.

Depencency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.facebook.business.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>facebook-java-business-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
import com.facebook.ads.sdk.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PageFeedPost {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws APIException {

        // https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-business-sdk/blob/main/examples/PageFeedPost.java

        String access_token = "<ACCESS_TOKEN>";
        String app_secret = "<APP_SECRET>";
        String app_id = "<APP_ID>";
        String id = "<PAGE_ID>";
        APIContext context = new APIContext(access_token).enableDebug(true);

        new Page(id, context).createFeed()
            .setMessage("This is a test value")
            .execute();

    }
}
```

Also, how to get all scheduled items from the planner?

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation provides details about how to publish photos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing#publish-a-photo

Accordingly, the JAVA SDK provides a method `public APIRequestCreatePhoto createPhoto()`, which you should use instead of `createFeed()`.

Similarly, the API explains how to schedule a post: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing#schedule-a-page-post

- you have to set `published` to `false`, which can be achieved using method`APIRequestCreatePhoto.setPublished` and
- you need to set the `schedule_publish_time` parameter using method `APIRequestCreatePhoto.setScheduledPublishTime`

Edit: Retrieving scheduled posts is possible using method `public APIRequestGetScheduledPosts getScheduledPosts()` of class `Page` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/scheduled_posts/).

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. The createPhoto doesn't have a ".addUploadFile" methode. Do you know how to upload a photo?

Comment: You can have a look at the graph API reference for photos (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) to find out, which fields exist at the endpoint. You have to specify a URL of the photo. The SDK provides method `APIRequestCreatePhoto.setUrl`